# Sanctum CSRF Cookie not sent when accessing from domain

Tags: laravel, csrf

I'm trying to build an app that will consume Laravel APIs and I'm trying to use Sanctum for authentication. I've check a whole bunch of videos and tutorials and one thing I've noticed is that they are all using localhost or 127.0.0.1 for demonstration purposes. 
However, one thing I'm missing out is actually figuring out how to work with the domains. 
In my case, I'm using Valet to serve the laravel app. And after configuring everything needed for sanctum, I'm left struggling with getting the CSRF cookie when request is sent to https://domain.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie.

In Postman I'm getting no cookies 
[image]

I started going nuts, and then I tried simple `php artisan serve` and made a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and by magic I got the cookies

[image]

Any explanation why this might happen will be great.

To note, I've set SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in my env file to include both localhost and domain.test.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add session domain in the .env file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.test
```

[and don't forget to add . (dot) before domain]